# sentencia if, no se como aplicarla

Tags: python

estoy codificando un pequeño programa de cobrar productos con la opcion de incluir el iva a productos y con la opcion de cobrar mas productos; estoy tratando usar la sentencia "IF" pero no he podido hacerlo; aparte quiero hacerlo con el ciclo "while" i poner dos sentencias if una para cuando el producto tenga iva y otra para cuando falte por cobrar un producto.
pds: soy notavo y estoy intentando aprender; agrego mi codigo.
agradeszco cualquier ayuda :)

```
#programa tienda de barrio 

#definicion de variables 
from re import S


iva=0.19
sub=0


def precioIva(p):
    IVA = precio * 0.19
    return IVA

#solucion preograma de venta 

while falta_por_cobrar:
    cantidad_prod=int(input("INGRESA LA CANTIDAD DEL PRODUCTO: "))
    precio=float(input("INGRESA EL VALOR DEL PRODUCTO: "))
    iva=str(input("EL PRODUCTO TIENE IVA: "))

    #sentencia para volver a cobrar productos

    falta_por_cobrar = input("¿FALTA ALGUN PRODUCTO POR COBRAR?: " )
    if falta_por_cobrar == S

    sub = cantidad_prod * precio

    #sentencia para añadir el iva a los productos que tengan iva 
    if iva == S:
        sub * iva
```

Comment: Como comentas en el comentario de la respuesta, tienes un error en la condición `if falta_por_cobrar == S`. Bien, `Pyhton` es un lenguaje que necesita mucho orden, y por lo tanto tabular el código bien. Fíjate que la sentencia `sub = cantidad_prod*precio` **NO ESTÁ DENTRO DEL IF**, para que se produzca dicha sentencia debes tabularla para que esté dentro del `if`. Por otro lado, te falta poner `:` (dos puntos) al final de la condición del `if`. (1/2)

Comment: Otro fallo que tienes es que comparas `S` con una variable que no existe. Si quieres comparar `falta_por_cobrar` con lo típico de leer por teclado una S o una N (Yes/No), debes poner dicha `S` entre comillas simples de la forma `'S'` (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchos problemas en ese código, el `while` no tiene condición de entrada, `falta_por_cobrar` está referenciada antes de ser asignada.

En ningún lado se calcula el iva, o sea, no se llama la función.

En varias partes haces comparación de string vs una variable inexistente (`S`): `if xyz == S:`

No estás acumulando los cálculos en la variable `sub`, si no que se está reescribiendo en cada iteración.

Consejo, no definas valores dentro de funciones, a menos que sean constantes (invariantes en el tiempo). Lo digo por el `0.19` dentro de la función. Imagínate que es un proyecto grande y cambia el IVA, tendrías que correr a cambiar todas las funciones donde está "quemado" ese valor.

Entonces, corrigiendo todo lo anterior:

```
def precioIva(p, iva):
    return p * iva
    
iva = 0.19
sub = 0

falta_por_cobrar = 'S'
while falta_por_cobrar.upper() == 'S':
    cantidad_prod = int(input("INGRESA LA CANTIDAD DEL PRODUCTO: "))
    precio = float(input("INGRESA EL VALOR DEL PRODUCTO: "))
    costo = cantidad_prod * precio
    
    tiene_iva = input("¿EL PRODUCTO TIENE IVA? S/[N]: ")
    if tiene_iva.upper() == 'S':
        costo += precioIva(costo, iva)
    print("Subtotal del producto:", costo)
    sub += costo
    
    falta_por_cobrar = input("¿FALTA ALGUN PRODUCTO POR COBRAR? S/[N]: " )

print()
print("El total de venta es:", sub)
```

Comment: gracias por las correciones amigo te agradezco, voy a cambiar esa variable del 0.19; estoy empezando

Answer (score -1):

Estas ocupando la variable iva de forma erronea

## lo defines como un valor numerico que no se usa

```
iva=0.19
```

## luego lo asignas con un string

```
iva=str(input("EL PRODUCTO TIENE IVA: "))
```

## luego lo comparas y lo multiplicas por un string

```
if iva == S:
        sub * iva
```

Comment: No lo habia notado, pero ya hice la correccion y cambien la variable "iva=str(input("EL PRODUCTO TIENE IVA: "))" por "prodIva=str(input("EL PRODUCTO TIENE IVA: "))" igualmente "if prodIva == S:" por que es hay que cito a la variable "STR"

Comment: pero  i verdadero problema es en la funcion "falta_por_cobrar = input("¿FALTA ALGUN PRODUCTO POR COBRAR?: " )
    if falta_por_cobrar == S